# Writing outside allocated memory

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, access-violation

Valgrind tells me that my application is writing outside the allocated memory. What could be the reason for this? The output looks like:

```
==18307== 1 errors in context 3 of 5:
==18307== Invalid write of size 8
==18307==    at 0x65A35F0: QDateTime::QDateTime() (in /usr/lib64/libQtCore.so.4.8.6)
==18307==    by 0xB752F5: ora::Patient::Patient(ora::Site*)(oraPatient.cxx:53)
==18307==    by 0xB359F2: main (main.cxx:32)
==18307==  Address 0x16b3b680 is 8 bytes after a block of size 328 alloc'd
==18307==    at 0x4C29118: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18307==    by 0xB359E2: main (main.cxx:32)
```

All members are known at compile time and there is no dynamic allocation happening anymore. The line referenced in `oraPatient.cxx:53` is the constructor. `sizeof(Patient)` returns 328 which is exactly the size which is allocated as valgrind states.

In my case it is always the last two members of this class. So if I comment them the next will be a `QString` and a `QDateTime`. That's why I do not think it has something to do with Qt itself.

Patient.h

```
#define SimpleProperty(member, _type) \
  public: \
  /**
   * @brief Set member of type _type.
   * @param _arg_##member Value to be set
   * @see m_##member for a more detailed description
   */ \
  Q_INVOKABLE void Set##member(_type _arg_##member) \
  { \
    m_##member = _arg_##member;\
  } \
  /**
   * @brief Get member of type _type.
   * @return Returns the value of ##member
   * @see m_##member for a more detailed description
   */ \
  Q_INVOKABLE _type Get##member() const\
  { \
    return m_##member;\
  } \
  protected: \
    _type m_##member; \

class Patient : public RTObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  QString ProposeRootFolderName() const;
  explicit Patient(ora::Site *parent = NULL);
  virtual ~Patient();
  Patient(const ora::Patient & other);
  bool operator==(const Patient &patient);
  bool operator!=(const ora::Patient & patient);
  Q_INVOKABLE virtual QString GetStringRepresentation(const bool compriseChildren = true) const;
  Q_INVOKABLE virtual bool IsValid() const;
  Q_INVOKABLE void SetSite(ora::Site * parent);
  Q_INVOKABLE void SetParent(ora::Site * parent);
  Q_INVOKABLE ora::Site * GetParent() const;
  Q_INVOKABLE ora::Site * GetSite() const;
  Q_INVOKABLE bool Serialize(QDataStream &stream) const;
  Q_INVOKABLE void Deserialize(QDataStream &stream);
  Q_INVOKABLE const QList<ora::Treatment *> & GetTreatments() const;
  Q_INVOKABLE ora::Treatment * GetTreatment(const int treatmentIndex) const;
  Q_INVOKABLE bool AppendTreatment(ora::Treatment * treatment);
  Q_INVOKABLE bool InsertTreatment(ora::Treatment * treatment, const int index);
  Q_INVOKABLE bool RemoveTreatment(const int treatmentIndex);
  Q_INVOKABLE bool RemoveTreatment(ora::Treatment * treatment);
  Q_INVOKABLE void ClearTreatments();
  Q_INVOKABLE QList<ora::StructureSet *> & GetStructureSets();
  Q_INVOKABLE ora::StructureSet * GetStructureSet(const int structureSetIdx) const;
  Q_INVOKABLE bool AppendStructureSet(ora::StructureSet * structureSet);
  Q_INVOKABLE bool InsertStructureSet(ora::StructureSet * structureSet, const int index);
  Q_INVOKABLE bool RemoveStructureSet(const int structureSetIdx);
  Q_INVOKABLE int RemoveStructureSet(ora::StructureSet * structureSet);
  Q_INVOKABLE void ClearStructureSets();
  Q_INVOKABLE const QMap<QString, PatientSetup*> &GetPatientSetups() const;
  Q_INVOKABLE PatientSetup *GetPatientSetup(const QString &patientSetupID) const;
  Q_INVOKABLE bool InsertPatientSetup(const QString &patientSetupID, PatientSetup *patientSetup);
  Q_INVOKABLE bool RemovePatientSetup(const QString &patientSetupID);
  Q_INVOKABLE bool RemovePatientSetup(PatientSetup *patientSetup);
  Q_INVOKABLE void ClearPatientSetups();
  Q_INVOKABLE const QList<ImagingProtocol *> &GetImagingProtocols() const;
  Q_INVOKABLE const QList<TreatmentOperation *> &GetTreatmentOperations() const;
  Q_INVOKABLE const QList<Reg23Configuration *> &GetRegistrationConfigurations() const;
  Q_INVOKABLE ImagingProtocol *GetImagingProtocol(const int i) const;
  Q_INVOKABLE TreatmentOperation *GetTreatmentOperation(const int i);
  Q_INVOKABLE Reg23Configuration *GetRegistrationConfiguration(const int i);
  Q_INVOKABLE TreatmentOperation *GetTreatmentOperation(const QString toId);
  Q_INVOKABLE Reg23Configuration *GetRegistrationConfiguration(const QString rcId);
  Q_INVOKABLE bool AppendImagingProtocol(ImagingProtocol *protocol);
  Q_INVOKABLE bool AppendTreatmentOperation(TreatmentOperation *to);
  Q_INVOKABLE bool AppendRegistrationConfiguration(Reg23Configuration *rc);
  Q_INVOKABLE bool RemoveImagingProtocol(const int i);
  Q_INVOKABLE bool RemoveTreatmentOperation(const int i);
  Q_INVOKABLE bool RemoveRegistrationConfiguration(const int i);
  Q_INVOKABLE bool RemoveImagingProtocol(ImagingProtocol *protocol);
  Q_INVOKABLE bool RemoveTreatmentOperation(TreatmentOperation *to);
  Q_INVOKABLE bool RemoveRegistrationConfiguration(Reg23Configuration *rc);
  Q_INVOKABLE void ClearImagingProtocols();
  Q_INVOKABLE void ClearTreatmentOperations();
  Q_INVOKABLE void ClearRegistrationConfigurations();
  Q_INVOKABLE bool InsertImagingProtocol(ImagingProtocol *protocol, const int i);
  Q_INVOKABLE bool InsertTreatmentOperation(TreatmentOperation *to, const int i);
  Q_INVOKABLE bool InsertRegistrationConfiguration(Reg23Configuration *rc, const int i);
  Q_INVOKABLE const QList<Study *> &GetStudies() const;
  Q_INVOKABLE Study *GetStudy(const int i) const;
  Q_INVOKABLE Study *GetStudy(const QString sid) const;
  Q_INVOKABLE bool AppendStudy(Study *stud);
  Q_INVOKABLE bool RemoveStudy(const int i);
  Q_INVOKABLE bool RemoveStudy(Study *stud);
  Q_INVOKABLE void ClearStudies();
  Q_INVOKABLE bool InsertStudy(Study *stud, const int i);
protected:
  Patient &operator=(const Patient&);
  virtual void Initialize();
  ora::Site *m_Site;
  QList<ora::Treatment*> m_Treatments;
  QList<ora::StructureSet*> m_StructureSets;
  QMap<QString, PatientSetup*> m_PatientSetups;
  QList<ImagingProtocol*> m_ImagingProtocols;
  QList<TreatmentOperation *> m_TreatmentOperations;
  QList<Study*> m_Studies;
  QList<Reg23Configuration *> m_RegistrationConfigurations;
  SimpleProperty(FirstName, QString)
  SimpleProperty(LastName, QString)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString FirstName READ GetFirstName WRITE SetFirstName)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString LastName READ GetLastName WRITE SetLastName)
  SimpleProperty(PatientID, QString)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString PatientID READ GetPatientID WRITE SetPatientID)
  SimpleProperty(OtherPatientIDs, QString)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString OtherPatientIDs READ GetOtherPatientIDs WRITE SetOtherPatientIDs)
  SimpleProperty(BarCodeID, QString)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString BarCodeID READ GetBarCodeID WRITE SetBarCodeID)
  SimpleProperty(IssuerOfPatientID, QString)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString IssuerOfPatientID READ GetIssuerOfPatientID WRITE SetIssuerOfPatientID)
  SimpleProperty(BirthDate, QDate)
  Q_PROPERTY(QDate BirthDate READ GetBirthDate WRITE SetBirthDate)
  SimpleProperty(PatientSex, QString)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString PatientSex READ GetPatientSex WRITE SetPatientSex)
  SimpleProperty(BirthTime, QTime)
  Q_PROPERTY(QTime BirthTime READ GetBirthTime WRITE SetBirthTime)
  SimpleProperty(OtherPatientNames, QString)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString OtherPatientNames READ GetOtherPatientNames WRITE SetOtherPatientNames)
  SimpleProperty(EthnicGroup, QString)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString EthnicGroup READ GetEthnicGroup WRITE SetEthnicGroup)
  SimpleProperty(Comments, QString)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString Comments READ GetComments WRITE SetComments)
  SimpleProperty(PatientSpeciesDescription, QString)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString PatientSpeciesDescription READ GetPatientSpeciesDescription WRITE SetPatientSpeciesDescription)
  SimpleProperty(PatientSpeciesCodeSequence, QString)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString PatientSpeciesCodeSequence READ GetPatientSpeciesCodeSequence WRITE SetPatientSpeciesCodeSequence)
  SimpleProperty(ResponsiblePerson, QString)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString ResponsiblePerson READ GetResponsiblePerson WRITE SetResponsiblePerson)
  SimpleProperty(ResponsiblePersonRole, QString)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString ResponsiblePersonRole READ GetResponsiblePersonRole WRITE SetResponsiblePersonRole)
  SimpleProperty(ResponsibleOrganization, QString)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString ResponsibleOrganization READ GetResponsibleOrganization WRITE SetResponsibleOrganization)
  SimpleProperty(HospitalID, QString)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString HospitalID READ GetHospitalID WRITE SetHospitalID)
  SimpleProperty(PatientSize, qreal)
  Q_PROPERTY(qreal PatientSize READ GetPatientSize WRITE SetPatientSize)
  SimpleProperty(PatientWeight, qreal)
  Q_PROPERTY(qreal PatientWeight READ GetPatientWeight WRITE SetPatientWeight)
  SimpleProperty(Address, QStringList)
  Q_PROPERTY(QStringList Address READ GetAddress WRITE SetAddress)
  SimpleProperty(CountryOfResidence, QString)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString CountryOfResidence READ GetCountryOfResidence WRITE SetCountryOfResidence)
  SimpleProperty(TelephoneNumbers, QStringList)
  Q_PROPERTY(QStringList TelephoneNumbers READ GetTelephoneNumbers WRITE SetTelephoneNumbers)
  SimpleProperty(Station, QString)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString Station READ GetStation WRITE SetStation)
  SimpleProperty(BirthName, QString)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString BirthName READ GetBirthName WRITE SetBirthName)
  SimpleProperty(Occupation, QString)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString Occupation READ GetOccupation WRITE SetOccupation)
  SimpleProperty(SmokingStatus, QString)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString SmokingStatus READ GetSmokingStatus WRITE SetSmokingStatus)
  SimpleProperty(PregnancyStatus, QString)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString PregnancyStatus READ GetPregnancyStatus WRITE SetPregnancyStatus)
  SimpleProperty(Attendant, QString)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString Attendant READ GetAttendant WRITE SetAttendant)
  SimpleProperty(AttendanceDate, QDateTime)
  Q_PROPERTY(QDateTime AttendanceDate READ GetAttendanceDate WRITE SetAttendanceDate)
  SimpleProperty(AbsenceDate, QDateTime)
  Q_PROPERTY(QDateTime AbsenceDate READ GetAbsenceDate WRITE SetAbsenceDate)
  SimpleProperty(LastAttendanceDate, QDateTime)
  Q_PROPERTY(QDateTime LastAttendanceDate READ GetLastAttendanceDate WRITE SetLastAttendanceDate)

private:

};
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const ora::Patient &patient);
QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &in, ora::Patient &patient);

} // namespace ora

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ora::Patient)
```

Patient.cxx

```
#include "oraPatient.h"

namespace ora
{

Patient::Patient(ora::Site *parent) : RTObject(parent)
{
  Initialize();

  m_Site = parent;
}

bool Patient::operator==(const Patient &patient)
{
  return true;
}


bool Patient::operator!=(const ora::Patient &patient)
{
  return !(*this == patient);
}

} // namespace ora
```

RTObject.cxx

```
#include "oraRTObject.h"

// SORRY
#include "oraCentralLoggingService.h"

namespace ora
{

RTObject::RTObject(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
  qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<ApprovalStatusType>("ora::RTObject::ApprovalStatusType");
  qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<BeamTypeType>("ora::RTObject::BeamTypeType");
  qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<PlanIntentType>("ora::RTObject::PlanIntentType");
  qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<PlanRelationshipType>("ora::RTObject::PlanRelationshipType");
  qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<PrimaryDosimeterUnitType>("ora::RTObject::PrimaryDosimeterUnitType");
  qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<RadiationTypeType>("ora::RTObject::RadiationTypeType");
  qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<RotationDirectionType>("ora::RTObject::RotationDirectionType");
  qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<ScanModeType>("ora::RTObject::ScanModeType");
  qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<TreatmentDeliveryTypeType>("ora::RTObject::TreatmentDeliveryTypeType");
  qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<ModeType>("ora::RTObject::ModeType");
  qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<RTObject::PatientPositionType>("ora::RTObject::PatientPositionType");
  qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<RTObject::QStringStringMap>("ora::RTObject::QStringStringMap");

  m_StreamVersion = 0;
  m_IsValid = true;
}

RTObject::RTObject(const RTObject &)
{
  m_StreamVersion = 0;
  m_IsValid = false;
}

RTObject::~RTObject()
{
}

} // namespace ora
```

Creating the patient: `new Patient();`

Comment: Can you paste the code valgrind refers to here?

Comment: "Why does my code, which I will not show to you, have memory issues?" Ask someone who *can* see your code.

Comment: Added code. The things which are missing are hopefully not relevant, otherwise I can post them as well.

Comment: Have you built from clean?  Including running `moc`?  It looks like code built to write to a bigger object is linked with code that allocated a smaller one.

Comment: Yes I tried but it did not help.

Comment: Be explicit: delete the shadow build folder completely, and build again.

Answer (score 1):

This was quite a stupid thing I did. One must simply not using `#ifdef` in a library which has not the same value in the application which uses the library. 
That lead to something that my applications header looked different to the compiler than the same header in the library which of course causes the application compiler to calculate wrong addresses.